# How to specify my Ruby installation folder to gems?

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, sass, rubygems

I installed Ruby 2.0 manually by running `apt-get install ruby2.0` then creating the symbolic link /usr/bin/ruby that points to /usr/bin/ruby2.0.

However, after doing this it seems that the gem command doesn't recognize the installation directory as it gives the error

> -bash: /usr/bin/gem: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

How can I specifically tell gem that my installation directory is /usr/bin/ruby2.0 instead of /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1? Looking inside the /usr/bin/gem file there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do so by modifying paths. I realize I could instead move the 2.0 files into the ruby1.9.1 folder but that seems like bad practice.

Comment: I would look into using a tool called rbenv. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv This allows you to easily manage different versions of Ruby. It is very widely used in the Ruby community.

Comment: You probably want to use `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby` to choose the default ruby interpreter instead of manually creating symlinks

Comment: @JuicyScripter "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for ruby" Hmm..

Comment: @kcdragon thanks for this, i'll try that if i can't figure it out without.